# OnMouseDrag and bool controller

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created 9 clone objects and U use *OnMouseDrag* function to move my objects.

First I drag object in the area zone and left button click to placed it in the map.

```
 void OnMouseDrag(){

        if(placed==false && placedArmyCounter<3){
        Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        mousePos.z = 0f;


            mousePos.x=Mathf.Round(mousePos.x);
            mousePos.y=Mathf.Round(mousePos.y);

            if( BoardManager.boardID==0 && mousePos.x>=0 && mousePos.x<=5 && mousePos.y>=0 && mousePos.y<=2){
            transform.position=new Vector2((mousePos.x),(mousePos.y));


            }
            if( BoardManager.boardID==1 && mousePos.x>=0 && mousePos.x<=7 && mousePos.y>=0 && mousePos.y<=3){
                transform.position=new Vector2((mousePos.x),(mousePos.y));


            }

        }

    }
```

Left click

```
if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1) )     
        {
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint((Input.mousePosition)), -Vector2.up);
            if(hit.collider != null)
            {


                GameObject target = hit.collider.gameObject;


                if(target.tag=="infantry"){
                    target.GetComponent<playerArmyMove>().Place();

                }

                if(target.tag=="archer"){
                    target.GetComponent<playerArmyMove>().Place();

                }

                if(target.tag=="horseman"){
                    target.GetComponent<playerArmyMove>().Place();

                }

            }


        }
```

place function

```
public void Place(){

        if(checkPlace==true){
            placed=false;
        }

        if(checkPlace==false){
            placed=true;
            placedArmyCounter+=1;

        }
    }
```

When placed is true object cannot move again and placedArmyController using for starting game

By the way, I want only 3 objects can place in map area.

But there is a problem if I don't click left button , I can add a lot of objects in the map.And I don't want to happen like that.

I know I need another controller which checks "is there any object in map area and is placed or not".But if I add the controller in *OnMouseDrag* function any object can not move.

Is there any suggestion?

P.S : Don't care checkPlace boolean in place function it is about detect collision.

Comment: i dont understand. could you maybe rephrase it please?

Comment: I have 9 different clone object and all use same script for placing in the map. But i want to only 3 of them can be in the map. For placing the clone object , first drag an object in the map zone and click mouse left button.when click the button , the object will be placed and can not move anymore. And if i replace for another object drag and then click left button everything is fine. But if i don't click left button and not placed the object , i can add all 9 objects in the map zone. so i need a controller which controls "is there any object in the map zone and is not place"

Comment: Some sort of OnMouseDrag+OnMouseUp combination might be working better to get more of a drag and drop behaviour.

Comment: Thanks Gunnar B. i added a controller OnMouseUp and place function. it works perfectly